# Maven build Failure on annotation

Tags: maven, annotations, ejb-3.0

I am trying to create a simple project with few stateless session beans.I have spent more than a week to find problem. Have tried various depenedencies but nothing worked. May be anyone can help me with this. But when i compile it with maven i get following error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \workspace\test\src\main\java\com\test\services\Test1ServiceImpl.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Stateless
[ERROR] @Stateless
[ERROR] \workspace\test\src\main\java\com\test\services\Test1ServiceImpl.java:[16,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Remote
My POM looks like this: 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>test-common</name>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
        <name>JBoss.org Maven repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-ejb3</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId> com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the jar which contains javax.ejb.* APIs.

Add the dependency to the following jar in your pom.xml.

For Java EE 6: http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar

Comment: oh thanks so much!!  I was struggling with it from so many days. You made my day ;-) Thanks novice

Answer (score 0):

"class Stateless" ? no package? Is your JAva source correct (with imports?)